# printing to "One Single CUPS Server" can not find queues if 'ServerName' is a CNAME

Tags: printing, cups

Running "OpenSuSE 11.4" with "cups-client-1.4.6-6.1.i586" installed, I try to use one single CUPS-server to do all my printing jobs / to manage my queues.

In **YaST -> printer** I've selected

> [x] Do All Printing Directly via One Single CUPS Server

and next to the field "name or IP Address" I enter `print` (as a CNAME for our print server), but no queue comes up in main window. If I change the ServerName to print server's hostname `dom-print`, everything works fine and queues are appearing properly.

---

Additional info:

nslookup tells the following about `print` ( `x`/`y`/`z` -> yeah, it's all top secret, you know.. ):

> Server:         10.0.x.y
>   Address:        10.0.x.y#53
>   
>   print.dom.tld    canonical name = dom-print.dom.tld.
>   Name:   dom-print.dom.tld
>   Address: 10.0.x.z